# Instances of Notification.Name in a Swift enum

Tags: swift, enums, swift3

I have several `notifications` in a `View Controller`, and would like to keep their names in an `Enum`:

```
enum KeyboardNotifications : Notification.Name{
        case didAppear = Notification.Name(rawValue:"cfisher.keyboardDidAppear")
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and I get a compile error: `raw value for enum case must be a literal value`.

Is there anyway around this?

I'm using Swift 3, BTW

Comment: With your extension method from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883162/implementing-expressiblebystringliteral-in-swift-3-0, `case didAppear = "cfisher.keyboardDidAppear"` would compile. It seems that you answered your own question :)

Comment: The compiler was driving me crazy and I thought I had the wrong approach. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

This way,

```
  enum Notes: String {

        case note1 = "note1"
        case note2 = "note2"

        var notification : Notification.Name  {
            return Notification.Name(rawValue: self.rawValue )
        }
    }

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notes.note2.notification ,object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be storing the Notifications in a `struct`.

For easier to read/cleaner code, you could use a global `func` for posting notifications.

```
struct KeyboardNotifications {
    static let didAppear = "cfisher.keyboardDidAppear"
    static let didSomethingElse = "cfisher.keyboardDidSomethingElse"
}

func postNotification(_ aName: String,
                      object anObject: Any?,
                      userInfo aUserInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: aName),
                                    object: anObject, 
                                    userInfo:aUserInfo)
}
```

Posting notifications will look like this:

```
postNotification(KeyboardNotifications.didAppear, object: nil)
```

This solution assumes that you're only posting to the default `NotificationCenter`.